# ViewModel: Check if fragment is resume or stop

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I perform network stuff inside `ViewModel` that repeat its fetching with interval of `10 seconds` with RxJava. However I do not want to fetch data from this API when my Fragment is not visible to screen for example is when I opened an Activity on a top of it I will have a code like `if(!isResume) return`. My question will be, is it okay to use a `MutableLiveData<Boolean>` where value will be updated in `onResume` and `onPause` so I can just ignore network request if not resume or is it against the concept of `MVVM`? We can do this but not sure if it is okay to do so.

Comment: Just extend your [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData) and hook into `onActive` and `onInactive` methods. That's what I do and it's MVVM compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `ViewModel` implement the interface `DefaultLifecycleObserver` (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver), and then you override the methods `onResume` and `onPause`. Update an internal boolean variable, e.g. `isResumed`, when those methods are called and you'll be able to check in other methods if the corresponding fragment is on the resumed state.

```
class YourViewModel : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    private var isResumed = false

    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        isResumed = true
    }

    override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        isResumed = false
    }
}
```

You also need to update your `Fragment` code to add that `ViewModel` as a lifecycle observer:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: YourViewModel // initialize it

    override fun onViewCreated(...) {
        lifecycle.addObserver(viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen answer like this before but is it safe to do so or it destroy the concept of ViewModel?

Comment: What is the advantage of using this instead of just changing the MutableLiveData<Boolean> value in `onResume` and `onPause` from Fragment?

Comment: The advantage is that you don't need to worry about that from your Fragment side. You just let the ViewModel query the lifecycle of your Fragment and do its thing.

Comment: that is what I only see as well

Comment: and when do we detach this observer cause it might cause leak

Comment: when you call the method "observe" on your LiveData from the Fragment side, you specify a LifecycleOwner (e.g. "viewLifecycleOwner") as parameter. that parameter controls when the observer will stop listening; in other words, it "deregisters" itself when it notices the Fragment isn't visible anymore.

Comment: take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata for more information about that.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't want my `ViewModel` to know about the `View`'s lifecycle, since it's conceptually wrong I think. If your `ViewModel` at some point gets shared between multiple `View`s, which one will stop the fetching?

You'd need a logic in that case, that is tied to the **number of subscribers** instead, and manage the subscriptions in your **View**.
Hopefully there are solutions for that:

1. Use an RxJava implementation instead of `LiveData`s, which stops execution when there are no subscribers, remove subscribers manually in `onPause`
2. ** Use **Kotlin Flows**, read [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda). You could expose a `Flow`, with `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` and collect it with

```
flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
```

Comment: Regarding #1 you mean use Disposal? If yes I do using that but what I want is to know if Fragment is visible since my Observable has interval for fetching data.

Comment: I am not relying on any views lifecycle nor context, I just want my ViewModel to know if the Fragment is resume or not to avoid unnecessary fetch from interval.