# Timer in ViewModel or in @Composable

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I started a timer in a view model, but then I realized it didn't stop when I was navigating to a different screen. (which means `onCleared` isn't called immediately unless `navController.popBackStack` is called)

```
init {
    getCurrent()
    autoSave()
    timer()
}

fun handleEvent(event: MainScreenEvents) {
    when (event) {
        MainScreenEvents.TogglePlay -> togglePlay()
    }
}

private fun togglePlay() {
    val state = _state.value
    if (state is MainScreenState.Loaded) { // better way?
        val isPlaying = !state.isPlaying
        _state.value = state.copy(
            isPlaying = isPlaying
        )
    }
}

private fun timer() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _state
            .mapNotNull { state ->
                when (state) {
                    is MainScreenState.Loaded -> state.isPlaying
                    else -> null
                }
            }
            .collectLatest { isPlaying ->
                while (isPlaying) {
                    when (val state = state.value) {
                        is MainScreenState.Loaded -> {
                            delay(calculateDelay())
                            incrementSomething()
                        }

                        else -> break
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```
sealed class MainScreenState {
    data object Loading: MainScreenState()
    data class Loaded(
        val article: Article,
        val isPlaying: Boolean = false,
    ): MainScreenState()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception, val id: Long? = null): MainScreenState()
}
```

Even if I [connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240724/viewmodel-check-if-fragment-is-resume-or-stop) the view model to the lifecycle of the activity to pause the timer in `onPause`, I doubt that compose navigation triggers lifecycle events. However, I think I could use a [DisposableEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect) and send an event to the view model in `onDispose`.

Would it make more sense to have `isPlaying` inside the composable function and have a `LaunchEffect` that starts the timer with `rememberCoroutineScope()`? (after a `delay`, send an event to the view model to increment some index)

Maybe I can rely on cold flows stopping when there are no collectors (which will happen when navigating to another screen) and do something like this:

```
    private val testCounter = MutableStateFlow(0) // do not collect
    val isPlaying = MutableStateFlow(false)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val testFlow = isPlaying
        .transformLatest { isPlaying ->
            while (isPlaying) {
                delay(1000)
                testCounter.value += 5
                emit(testCounter.value)
            }
        }
```